# Include Record Count within File Transfer Activity Filename

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

We are working on an automation that needs to export a file in the format of `EXPORT_202206231705034_XXXX.TXT`, where `XXXX` is the number of records in the file.

Is there a way to do this?  (Or perhaps run a Script Activity afterwards to update the filename)

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.

I'll let you figure out how to get the Data Extension row count. As for the automation activities, you'll have to dynamically update the filespec in the Extract and the File Transfer Activities via REST API...which you can do with SSJS.

**I'd suggest building this in Postman first, then translating it to SSJS.**

Here are a couple of example SSJS functions that interact with those entities.  You'll need to retrieve a bunch of object properties in preparation.

```javascript
function updateDataExtract(restBase,authToken,DataExtractDefinitionId,DataExtractPayload) {

    var url = restBase + '/automation/v1/dataextracts/' + DataExtractDefinitionId;

    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
    req.method = "PATCH";
    req.postData = Stringify(DataExtractPayload);

    try {

        var resp = req.send();
        var resultStr = String(resp.content);
        var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultStr);

        return resultJSON;

    } catch(e) {

        var resultJSON = {"errorcode": 1}
        return resultJSON

    }

    return resultJSON
}
```

Where the incoming payload is something like:

```javascript
var DataExtractPayload = {
    "dataExtractDefinitionId": DataExtractObject.dataExtractDefinitionId,
    "dataExtractTypeId": DataExtractObject.dataExtractTypeId,
    "fileSpec": FileName,
    "startDate": StartDate,
    "endDate": EndDate
}
```

Here's the File Transfer one:

```javascript
function updateFileTransfer(restBase,authToken,FileTransferObjectID,FileTransferPayload) {

    var url = restBase + '/automation/v1/filetransfers/' + FileTransferObjectID;
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
    req.method = "PATCH";
    req.postData = Stringify(FileTransferPayload);

    try {

        var resp = req.send();
        var resultStr = String(resp.content);
        var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultStr);

        return resultJSON;

    } catch(e) {

        var resultJSON = {"errorcode": 1}
        return resultJSON

    }

    return resultJSON
}
```

Where the incoming payload is something like:

```javascript
var FileTransferPayload = {
  "id": FileTransferObjectID,
  "fileTransferLocationId": FileTransferObject.fileTransferLocationId,
  "filespec": FileName
}
```

My use-case: dumping out 2 years of tracking data to load into a data warehouse.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for this info!  So I think that I see that your code is taking the File Transfer object, getting its properties, then patching the results.  Somewhere after `  req.postData = Stringify(DataExtractPayload);` we should manipulate the file format as we want it and then let the script continue to post back the changes - is that roughly correct?  (If so, I get the idea and can run with this)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense.  Thanks for the tip on the approach!